# How to pass indexPath from button inside footer to segue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsindexpath

I'm working on a custom layout collectionView which has quilt look and each section has a footer. Two buttons are inside footer and each button has a segue to another view(I set segues using IB).

Footer has its own indexPath which was assigned in a UICollectionViewFlowLayout class(Where I made a custom layout). The indexPath of footer is like this - {section - row} {0-0} {1-0} {2-0}....

I want to keep this indexPath information to use at the another view which is linked to two buttons.

I tried "convertPoint: toView: ... indexPathForRowAtPoint" way but didn't work. I think it's because the buttons are not belong to collectionViewItem but belong to Footer.

In this situation, what is the best way of passing each footerView's indexPath to segue?

Any solution with code example will be greatly appreciated.

```
// CollectionView DataSource

 - (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
            viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind
                                  atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    Footer *footerview = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter
                                                        withReuseIdentifier:@"Footer"
                                                               forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // set button images and labels
    [footerview setButton];
    // debug code : show current section number
    footerview.footerLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Section %li", (long)indexPath.section];

    return footerview;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"SeeAllPictures"]) {

        // how to pass indextPath?

    }
    else if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"GoDiary"]) {

        // how to pass indextPath?

    }
}
```

Below is header of Footer class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Footer : UICollectionReusableView

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *footerLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *seeAllPictures;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *goDiary;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *seeAllPicturesImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *seeAllPicturesLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *goDiaryImage;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *goDiaryLabel;

- (void)setButton;

@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

imagine a reusable view with two buttons (leftButton and rightButton). in your reusable view classes .h file add a property for the indexpath:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *indexPath;
```

then in your viewcontrollers **viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind** method:

```
CustomFooterView *footerView = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter withReuseIdentifier:@"FooterView" forIndexPath:indexPath];
footerView.indexPath = indexPath;

[footerView.leftButton addTarget:self action:@selector(leftButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[footerView.rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(rightButtonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

then implement the two methods:

```
- (void)leftButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"LeftButtonSegue" sender:sender];
}

- (void)rightButtonTapped:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"RightButtonSegue" sender:sender];
}
```

and finally in your viewcontrollers **prepareForSegue** method:

```
CustomFooterView *footerView = (CustomFooterView *)((UIButton *)sender).superview;
NSLog(@"perform segue from indexpath %ld, %ld", (long) footerView.indexPath.section, (long) footerView.indexPath.row);
```

**IMPORTANT**

the buttons have to be direct childs of the reusable view to make

```
(CustomFooterView *)((UIButton *)sender).superview
```

work. and of course you have to connect the segues **LeftButtonSegue** and **RightButtonSegue** in storyboard.

Comment: This works!! Thanks million times!! English is not my first language so your code sample really helped me to understand. Thanks again!

Comment: you're welcome :) maybe you could vote my answer up and set it as the accepted one?! glad i could help!

Comment: It's embarassing to say but I stuck to right after your solution. Would you please look up my next problem? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29833284/how-to-pass-indexpath-from-segue-to-destination-view)